# how can i do to make a break in a "place order" process , and show a box to take the password sent to the user , during the checkout

Tags: checkout, rest-api, onepage-checkout, payment-gateway, modal-popup

**I am adding custom online payment, but the workflow uses a time password in the last step of the process. How can I do to make a break in a "place order" process, and show a box to take the password sent to the user?**

[image]